# Facebook link returned from Graph API, but leads to “Content Not Found” page for some but not all users

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-authentication

My app is trying to link to a user's Facebook Home page like this, in order to send a message to the user:

```
        reachOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Navigate to person's Facebook page to send a message.
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://facebook.com/" + idArray[selectedPosition]));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

idArray[] contains a list of app-scoped Facebook IDs. This works fine for a number of users, but not for others. I asked one person if he was blocking access to his page, but he said he was not. Also, from what I read in the [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/overview/), app users cannot turn off access to their Home pages:

> User Control
>   Facebook Login allows a person to grant only a subset of permissions that you ask for to your app, except for public profile, which is always required. This is available as a separate screen in the login dialog when you ask for permissions. Your app should handle the case where someone had declined to grant your app one of the permissions you requested.

Anyone have an idea what's going on or can you suggest an alternative approach?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the user_link permission is a no-op. Regardless of whether this permission is granted, users can only link to pages of friends. Totally ridiculous.